# Deny all ports and allow few ports in azure, this make the site not to load

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

In azure portal, currently all ports are open, I need to deny all ports and allow only wanted once. When i do that, the websites are not accessible. The pic below is the inbound ports. I need to deny the first one(which is circled in red).

[image: view snapshot]

Do i have to allow any other port as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you should check the priority of your NSG rules.

[image]

The rule that you deny any ports should have the lowest priority. It means the rule's priority number is the largest.

**Also, you don't need add this rule. Azure's default rule denies all ports except the ports you opened.**
[image]

More information about Azure NSG please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg).